# Managed package Custom App and tabs not visible on production org

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, permissions, licenses, lightning-tabset

I installed a managed package on Production org. After successful installation of the package, the custom app and custom tabs from the package are not visible in the app launcher(6 dots). This only happens in this production and in other org, it seems to be fine.

I have assigned all the necessary licenses and permission for that user. But still, the user can't access the custom app and tabs.

Could you please help, what might be wrong here?

Comment: A couple of questions: when the package was installed, was it "installed for all users" or just admins? How have you checked the required permissions?

Comment: the package was installed for admins and the user who wants to access the custom app and tab is an admin. And I make sure the user had permission assigned.